# Firebase Cloud Messaging override onDeletedMessages()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Do I really need to override onDeletedMessages()? I have read that

> In some situations, FCM may not deliver a message. This occurs when there are too many messages (>100) pending for your app on a particular device at the time it connects or if the device hasn't connected to FCM in more than one month. In these cases, you may receive a callback to FirebaseMessagingService.onDeletedMessages()

What will happen if I don't override this method and the above situation occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't override `onDeletedMessages()`, then you won't know about the case that was described in the documentation.  Specifically, if messages are dropped for the stated reasons, your client app will have no idea that happened.

The API obviously does not require you to override this method, otherwise it would have been marked `abstract`, requiring you to provide an implementation.  But as [the API docs suggest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService.html#onDeletedMessages()), this is your opportunity to fully sync with the server to get a hold of any missing data from dropped messages.